# postgresql with 5432 not able to connect remotely

Tags: postgresql

I have the following configuration done:

```
root@testubuntu:~# cat /etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf | grep -i listen
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
root@testubuntu:~# netstat -na | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     33115    /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

I'm able to telnet from the same server but not from a remote one, even though all the ports are opened in the hardware firewall.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is the server behind a router? if so, you will likely need to forward the port from the WAN side to the LAN side in order to access it from outside the LAN

Comment: Even i have tried to telnet from same VLAN(other server). still not able to telnet

Comment: This is resolved. ufw was in inactive state but still iptables -L showing that only 22 port is allowed. flushed the iptables and enabled the ufw firewall and allowed all the rules needed to allow the traffic.